# Select columns outside of group by

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to select the first and last click by each ID, along with the corresponding source. Here is a sample table:

```
ID   Click      Source  
--------------------------
1      1        Google  
1      2        Facebook   
1      3        Yahoo   
2      1        Google
2      2        Yahoo 
3      1        Facebook
4      1        Yahoo
5      1        Pinterest
5      2        Google
```

Here is the desired result:

```
ID   First      Last
-------------------------
1    Google     Yahoo
2    Google     Yahoo
3    Facebook   Facebook
4    Yahoo      Yahoo
5    Pinterest  Google
```

I've already managed to get the first click by simply setting click=1 in the where clause. I am not able to get MAX(click) without grouping by ID and Source. When I include the Source in the group by I don't get the results I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can join two derived tables getting the first and last click per id using `DISTINCT ON` on the common ID.

```
SELECT f.id,
       f.source "first",
       s.source "last"
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
                    id,
                    source
                    FROM elbat
                    ORDER BY id ASC,
                             click ASC) f
            INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
                               id,
                               source
                               FROM elbat
                                    ORDER BY id ASC,
                                             click DESC) s
                       ON s.id = f.id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=241934f5026f527fd2b474c14f96dfcc)

Answer (score 0):

sticky bit's solution is quite good, but you can also do this with window functions.  You should test to see which one works better for you:

```
select distinct id, 
       first_value(source) OVER (partition by id order by click),
       last_value(source)  OVER (partition by id order by click 
                                RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id;
```